React Grid Layout - Only Drag on Movement
I'm currently working on a project using React-Grid-Layout where I can arrange multiple widgets in the layout, i.e., move and resize them. The widgets are interactable.
Now, to my problem: As soon as I click on the widget, it becomes a draggable.
What have I tried? I have attempted both creating my own Grid Item and modifying the Node module itself, but I did not achieve the desired result.
How can I make it draggable only during movement?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have the same issue; I want the user to be able to drag items only when they perform a long press on the items. I have tried multiple approaches, but I have not been able to find a solution.

Have you tried to set the isDraggable prop to false?
e.g.
<ResponsiveGridLayout
....
isDraggable={false}
/>
